# Send Bitmap from android to php script

Tags: php, android, imageview

I'm trying to send image from android application to PHP script on server, but I can't.
I got the image from ImageView and store it in SQLite database, than I got the image from database and send it the the server.
On server, I'm sore the image to database.

Here is the code:

1. Got image from IvageView and store it to database:
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

   ```
    ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.iv_foto01);
    foto = (BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    foto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    String str_img = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

    values.put("foto", str_img);

    db.insert("fotos", null, values);
   ```
2. Got image from database and send it server:

   ```
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM fotos", null);
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   JSONObject foto = new JSONObject();
   foto.put("foto", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("foto")));

   HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
   try {
      URL url = new URL("http://www.server.ru/foto/add_foto_record.php");
      urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
      urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
      urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
      urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
      urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
      urlConnection.connect();
      OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
      out.write(foto.toString());
      out.close();
      int HttpResult = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
   }
   ```
3. Save image to database on server (add_foto_record.php):

   ```
    include("dbconnect.php");

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json);

    $query = "INSERT INTO fotos (foto) VALUES ('".$obj->foto."')";
    mysql_query($query);
   ```
4. Test saved image on server (test_image.php):

   ```
    include("dbconnect.php");

    $query= "SELECT * FROM fotos WHERE";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $f=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $blob_data = base64_decode($f['foto']);

    $img = imagecreatefromstring($blob_data);
    if ($img !== false) {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($img, NULL, 100);
        imagedestroy($img);
    } else {
        echo 'Произошла ошибка.';
    }
   ```

And when I'm trying to open http://www.server.ru/foto/test_image.php I got a error:
Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in test_image.php on line 10 Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Passed data is not in 'JPEG' format in test_image.php on line 10 Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Couldn't create GD Image Stream out of Data in test_image.php on line 10.

Can anyone help me? How I must code image on android, sent it to server and decode it on server?

Thanks!

Comment: What is foto_food_cursor ? It looks as if you send a base64 encoded jpg instead of the jpg itself.

Comment: "foto_food_cursor" - it's a misprint, the right is "cursor" instead of "foto_food_cursor" - thank for it :-).

Comment: Yes, I'm got the bitmap from image view, convert it to byty array, than convert it to base64 string (it's needed for sending data in json, how I think). Than I got that base64 string, decode it and than, with imagecreatefromstring, I'm trying to create an jpeg image.

Comment: Well, the problem was in this string:
String str_img = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: Well, the problem was in this string:
String str_img = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
Istead of Base64.DEFAULT is needed to use Base64.NO_WRAP, because DEFAULT flag insert a lot of /r/n symbols in the encoded string. And if to use NO_WRAP flag all data encoded as one string.